# Storage and downloading files

Tags: sd-card, storage, downloading, files

I bought a new phone and everytime I save a picture from Twitter, the browser or a bbm profile it always saves in my phone storage not my SD card. I was wondering if there's a way to make them save instantly on the SD card and show in the gallery.

I use a Huawei Honor 3c running Jelly Bean 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

In your settings, under storage, there should be a option to change your default write disk. If you change that to SD card, it should save your media to the card.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped. But is it going to save media only to sd or even apps. ?

Comment: Only media, it does't seem to work for all apps though. If you what to move apps to the SD card it is done in setting/apps(or app management). You will need to tap on the app you want to move, and then there is usually a button to move it to the card. Some manufactures have this feature disabled for some reason, so hopefully it is available on your device.